# R package Ecdat stopped working

Tags: r, package

Before (1 week ago) the R package Ecdat was working and I have not changed anything, now I've tried to re-install the package, to have a look on the directory installation and the version it access it, and still couldn't find any answer.

I have tried with both RStudio and R to manage the problem.

```
library("Ecdat", lib.loc="C:/Users/Melonfarmer Johnes/Documents/R/win-library/2.15")
plot(Capm[,"rmrf"],Capm[,"rcon"])
Error in plot(Capm[, "rmrf"], Capm[, "rcon"]) : object 'Capm' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would have ever worked. The `data` instruction to load your `Capm` dataset is missing :

```
library(Ecdat)
data(Capm)
plot(...)
```

Comment: than you very much for your help

Comment: If this answer solved your problem, you can check the green mark in order it to indicate it to other users.